# Can I configure Swype to use two different languages for keyboard layout and spell checking?

Tags: keyboard, spellcheck

With my built-in iPhone keyboard that is easily possible, but I can't seem to find the setting on Swype.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, that's possible in Swype.** And in SwiftKey, too, by the way. Let me walk you through how I did it. But let me tell you *why* first.

For Stack Exchange, I use:

- **US English** spelling, since we're on a US website. Though, as a European, I should advocate UK spelling. Then again, the UK doesn't seem to advocate being European.
- A **German** keyboard layout, i.e. QWERTZ instead of QWERTY, because I've been using that layout for physical keyboards for the last couple of decades.

With the iPhone, it's easy to set those two differently. With third-party keyboards, not so much. But it is possible:

### Swype

Preconditions: You have bought the app and performed basic configuration so that you can access Swype as a virtual keyboard in your apps.

Steps:

1. Open **any app** that can access the Swype keyboard.
2. Select **Swype** as input method.
3. Press and hold the **space bar**, then slide up to **More Languages**.
4. *Do not click on any language!* Instead, for the language you want to configure, e.g. "English" (the US variant is implied), click on the **right arrow >**. It took me a while to discover this.
5. Choose the layout that you want, e.g. "QWERTZ" in my case. *Voilà.*

### SwiftKey

Preconditions: You have downloaded the app and performed basic configuration so that you can access SwiftKey as a virtual keyboard in your apps.

Steps:

1. Open the **SwiftKey** app.
2. Go to **Languages**. Under Downloaded Languages, you should see at least "English (US)" and "QWERTY"
3. Click on **switch layout** for a language.
4. Choose the layout that you want, e.g. "QWERTZ" in my case. *Voilà.*

> PS: I haven't quite made up my mind as to which of the two apps I actually prefer. I see immediate differences, but no killer criterion yet. I'll keep testing both for a while longer.

Comment: still not using both languages spelling.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two languages simultaneously, this is device wide, not specific to swype. However swype is bilingual and you can set the keyboard to any language they support by holding down the swype icon button and then selecting the settings icon and choose a language according to your needs. Auto complete and keyboard layouts change respectively to the language you select. Characters are localized.

Hold down the swype icon button :

[image: pic1]

Until the settings gear populates, select it and navigate to Languages to alter your settings

[image: pic2]

Comment: Maybe it's specific to my German iOS, but using the standard keyboards, I can set English as *language*, but the German QWERTZ (instead of US QWERTY) as my *keyboard layout*. Sadly, Swype registers as a totally separate keyboard and does not use my existing settings.